# inline and operator overloading woes

Tags: f#

I'm experimenting with inline and operators....not a specific application.

based on reading things like
http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/11/15/typeclasses-for-fsharp/
but not understanding it.

so.

I can make

```
type HelperType = HelperType with   
   static member (=>) (d:HelperType,x: list<char>) = fun y -> x @ y    
   static member (=>) (d:HelperType,x:array<char>) = fun y -> Array.append x y
   static member (=>) (d:HelperType,x:string     ) = fun y -> x + y

let inline append x = HelperType => x

let x1 = append "" ""
let x1 = append [|'a'|] [|'b'|]
```

work...and sort of understand whats going on.

but lets try to overload of just the types rather than the values...so I go...

```
type TypeOf<'t> = | TypeOf

type HelperType = HelperType with   
   static member (<*>) (d:HelperType,x:TypeOf<list<char>>     )   = fun x y -> x @ y
   static member (<*>) (d:HelperType,x:TypeOf<array<char>>     )   = fun x y -> Array.append x y
```

i.e. I don't actually need a value of the type just some proxy type value

and I go

```
let inline append2 (x : ^t) = (HelperType <*> (TypeOf :> TypeOf< ^t>)) x
```

and I get...

```
Error       A unique overload for method 'op_LessMultiplyGreater' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: static member HelperType.( <*> ) : d:HelperType * x:TypeOf<char array> -> ('a0 [] -> 'a0 [] -> 'a0 []), static member HelperType.( <*> ) : d:HelperType * x:TypeOf<char list> -> ('a0 list -> 'a0 list -> 'a0 list)
```

but whats the difference here between the first working example and the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between both append functions is that the second one knows the type to resolve, it would be  `TypeOf`  of 'something', it just don't know 'something', but the `append` in the first example has no clue to which type it would resolve so it defers the overload resolution to the calling site.

So the second example attempts to do the overload resolution and fails.

**UPDATE**

You might be interested in something like this:

```
type HelperType = HelperType with   
   static member (<*>) (d:HelperType, _:list<char> ) = fun (x:list<char>) y -> x @ y
   static member (<*>) (d:HelperType, _:array<char>) = fun (x:array<char>) y -> Array.append x y

let inline append2 x y :'T = (HelperType <*> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>) x y
```

But it will need to know the return type in advance:

```
let x1 : array<char> = append2 [|'a'|] [|'b'|]
```

or you can change it as you already figured out:

```
let inline append2 (x:'T) y :'T = (HelperType <*> Unchecked.defaultof<'T>) x y
```

But then what's the point of resolving on the output parameter?

Well in this case makes no sense, but for type functions it would.

Comment: let me talk it through....so the second one knows MORE...so it tries to resolve it, but cant so fails...but doesn't defer it to the calling site? whilst the first one knows nothing, so doesn't bother....seems weird

Comment: is there a way to fix it?

Comment: That's the way the compiler is written. If you tell me what are you trying to achieve I might be able to suggest something.

Comment: so the problem with the original append, is that's fine...IF there is a value to pass, but lets say I want a "zero" function or "identity" function that returns a value....then there is no value to pass (I may have to annotate the types to force the inference).

Comment: What seems weird is that if the compiler tried and failed but then noted that as its an inline function, then leave it to the call site, it would then be able to infer the types.

Comment: So in summary you are saying that the compiler looks at the code, if it knows nothing about the types involved it will leave it to the call site, if it knows something (i.e. it knows its an array or list) but doesn't know the type parameter, it attempts to resolve it...if it fails then it fails EVEN if it potentially could have resolved it IF it had left it to the call site? What I want to do is derive the function from just the types, because some functions don't have any parameters.

Comment: I guess you want a type function, that is a function taking no parameter but depending on the return type? Is that correct? If so there is a way to do that.

Comment: hmmm I'm getting "could not resolve the ambiguity inherent in the use of the operator"...at the call site....I understand what you've done.

Comment: let x1 = append2 [|'a'|] [|'b'|]

Comment: Ive marked it as the answer, I think you have answered what the compiler is doing....though it seems a tad frustrating, that it fails...I see what your workaround is...though I cant get it to work

Comment: let inline append2 (x : ^t) y  = (HelperType <*> Unchecked.defaultof< ^t>) x y

Comment: so its genuinely an answer....though a slightly expensive one...I'll take it...thanks

Comment: Thanks. If you do ``let x1 : array<char> = append2 [|'a'|] [|'b'|]`` it will work because of course it will need to know in advance the return type. For this example it will make no sense. Since what you want to achieve is perfectly doable, I would suggest to post it in a separate question, something like how to create a type function based on overloads or static constraints. Give a concrete example and I'm sure I would be able to help.

Comment: Alternatively you can have a look at how the function ``empty()`` is [implemented in FsControl](https://github.com/gmpl/FsControl/blob/master/FsControl.Core/Monoid.fs) but it doesn't follow the same convention. Also note that I'm the auther of the blog you were reading, if you don't understand something there you can post a comment and I will be happy to answer there.

Comment: aha nice....I have downloaded FsControl, but it wont compile...the error is too complicated for me to understand....but that's a bit frustrating, I'll look at empty()

Comment: static member inline Invoke() = 
        let inline call_2 (a:^a, b:^b) = ((^a or ^b) : (static member Empty: _*_ -> _) b, a)
        let inline call (a:'a) = call_2 (a, Unchecked.defaultof<'r>) :'r
        call Unchecked.defaultof<Empty>

Comment: Weird, it compiles on myget, anyway you can add an issue with the error message you are getting. Make sure you compile in RELEASE mode.